# CSV in PHP load it and read it

Tags: php, variables, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file in PHP and load its values into variables and then read them. I've not been able to find out a proper tutorial for this. Please help as am a newbie to coding and PHP. Any code with some explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/fgetcsv will be your first starting point. It has an example as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv), some tutorials available using google: [here](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=read%20csv%20php%20tutorial%20fgetcsv&oq=read%20csv%20php%20tutorial%20fgetcsv&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2743l4885l0l8l8l0l3l0l0l744l744l6-1).

Comment: is it possible for me to read the line, separate the values and assign them each to a variable i.e. kat,berlin,germany  assign kat to $username=kat berlin=city germany=country...I want to do this in the code and not in the CSV file. My idea is basically to take the values from CSV and compare them for output

Comment: I really suggest you read one of the tutorials are go from there. To answer your question: yes it is possible.